# Verify connectivity to a server on a UDP port

Tags: telnet, udp, hp-ux

I want to know if a HP-UX machine can communicate to a remote machine (which I don't have control over) on a particular port using UDP.

I tried telnet, but it doesn't look like it supports UDP. I would use netcat, but I was unable to find any bundle. This machine is in production so I don't want to mess around compliling or installing things too much... (nmap, netcat from source...)

Any simple way to do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Pinging a UDP port is kind of tricky, since there are no **connections**, per se. If you don't have control over the remote host, then you might never really know whether your UDP datagrams are actually being received. I assume you already know whether the remote host is reachable, via `ping`, `traceroute`, `mtr`, etc. (If not, check that first!)

Next, since you don't have `netcat`, you'll need some way of generating UDP packets.

The `bash` shell sends UDP packets when you redirect data to the special device `/dev/udp/host/port`. For example:

```
#!/bin/bash
host="10.10.10.10"
port=12345
echo "PING" >/dev/udp/$host/$port
```

Python, of course, is also fully capable of UDP, e.g.

```
#!/bin/python
import socket
host="10.10.10.10"
port=12345
udp_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
udp_sock.sendto('PING', (host, port))
```

Regardless of how you contrive to generate your UDP "ping" packet, you'll want to know whether the target received it. If the target port is open (i.e. a service is listening at the given port), then what happens will be application-defined. Hopefully, you will notice some behaviour or indication from the remote system.

If the target port is closed (i.e. no service is listening at that port), then you **should** get an ICMP error packet back in response. Use your favourite wire-level network sniffer to watch for it. Or, perhaps your HP-UX system logs ICMP errors somewhere (sorry, I don't have any experience with HP-UX).

Unfortunately, if the target is firewalled, you may not get a response when the target port is closed. The only surefire way to know if the remote host is responsive is to run your UDP-data-dependent application and watch the network traffic.

Answer (score 10):

You can use `netcat`. In OSX, this is my command:

```
$ nc -vnzu <IP> <PORT>
found 0 associations
found 1 connections:
1: flags=82<CONNECTED,PREFERRED>
outif (null)
src <SOURCE IP> port <SOURCE PORT>
dst <DEST IP> port <DEST PORT>
rank info not available
```

Comment: Perfect, nc works for everything!